# common Lispをmacにインストールし開発する方法について

Tags: lisp

初歩的な質問で申し訳ございません。Land of Lispを読みLispを学習しようと思ったのですが、CLISPを公式サイト(http://clisp.cons.org)　からインストールしなさいと書かれており、やろうとしたのですがわからないです。なにをどうすればわからない状態なので詳しく教えていただけなでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

複数の方法があります。

### A. パッケージマネジャーを使う

ソフトウェアを簡単にインストールできるように、それぞれのソフトウェアをひとつのパッケージにまとめ、パッケージごとに管理できるようにする仕組みが[パッケージマネジャー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0)です。まずはパッケージマネジャーをインストールし、その後パッケージマネジャーからパッケージをインストールするという流れになります。

CLISPのホームページには、Mac 向けにみっつのパッケージマネジャーが紹介されています。("Get CLISP" の部分です。)

#### Homebrew

Mac 向けによく使われているパッケージマネジャーのひとつです。2019年1月現在、個人的にはこれがお勧めです。

1. Homebrew をインストールする。
2. `brew install clisp`

#### MacPorts

Mac 向けによく使われているパッケージマネジャーのひとつです。

1. MacPorts をインストールする。
2. `sudo port install clisp` または `sudo port install swig-clisp` (後者は CLISP に加え SWIG もインストールします。とりあえず当面の内はどちらを選んでも OK のはずです)

#### Fink

Mac で使うことができるパッケージマネジャーのひとつです。

1. Fink をインストールする。
2. `fink install clisp`

### B. ソースコードからビルドする

慣れている方向けの方法です。CLISPのソースコードは公開されているので、自分でイチからビルドして使うことができます。

パッケージマネジャーからのインストールだと、ソフトウェアがアップデートされてもパッケージがアップデートされるのを待たないといけません。これが待ちきれない場合は自分でビルドすることになります。